# I'm writing a basic command line (UDP) server/listener in swift using Xcode. #GCDAsyncUdpSocket doesnt call any of my delegates

Tags: xcode, swift, sockets, udp

This is my very first program in Swift. I'm writing a basic command line (UDP) server/listener in swift using Xcode. I'm able to send data i.e. a string with characters 'testing' via the "sendData" call (verified through wireshark). However I can't seem to invoke any of the delegate callbacks. For "sendData", I've checked the implementation within #GCDAsyncUdpSocket's main file and I see that none of the delegates are called unless send we see a particular error (resolve error) in which case the "didNOTSendDataWithTag" is called.

But if "beginReceiving" is called, it does NOT invoke "didReceiveData" callback. I cant seem to find figure out why. Also "beginReceiving is suppose to be recursive (Calls itself forever I assume) according to its implementation. But my program exits quickly without any errors. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
import Cocoa
import CocoaAsyncSocket

class udpListener : GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {

var udpSock : GCDAsyncUdpSocket?
let listenPort : UInt16 = 14000
let data = "testing".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let toAddress = "127.0.0.1"
let connectPort : UInt16 = 14001


init () {

    udpSock = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

    do {

        try udpSock!.bindToPort(listenPort, interface: "lo0")  // Swift automatically translates Objective-C methods that produce
                                                  // errors into methods that throw an error according to Swift’s native error handling functionality.
    }
        catch _ as NSError {
        print("Issue with binding to Port")
        return }

   do {

         try udpSock!.beginReceiving()
    }

        catch _ as NSError {
        print("Issue with receciving data")
        return }
}

func sendData() {

    udpSock!.sendData(data, toHost: toAddress, port: connectPort, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
}

}



//    Delegate CallBacks


@objc  func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromAddress address: NSData!, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject!) {

    let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(str)
}

@objc  func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didSendDataWithTag tag: Int) {

    print("didSendDataWithTag")
}

@objc  func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didNotSendDataWithTag tag: Int, dueToError error: NSError!) {

    print("didNOTSendDataWithTag")
}
```

}

I'm instantiating an instance of the class from the main swift file and calling its methods in this order. Is this correct or am I missing something here

```
import Foundation


var dnsListener = udpListener()
    dnsListener.sendData()
```

Here's the screenshot of the wireshark results

Answer (score 1):

The main thread does not have any loop to keep it from exiting, so the execution is finished before the message is sent. If a loop or delay is added to main(), the message will be sent.
The other problem with this code is that the delegates are set to run on the main queue. The main queue is busy running the loop or delay, and can not execute the delegate code. By creating a new delegate queue, the code in the delegate functions will run.

The following code works in Swift 3.

Main code:

```
import Foundation

var dnsListener = UdpListener()

for i in 1...3 {
    print("Sending data \(i)")
    dnsListener.sendData()
    sleep(3)
}
print("Execution finished")
```

UdpListener code:

```
import Foundation
import CocoaAsyncSocket

class UdpListener : NSObject, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {

    var udpSock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket?
    let listenPort: UInt16 = 14000
    let data = "testing".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let toAddress = "127.0.0.1"
    let connectPort: UInt16 = 14001


    override init() {
        super.init()

        let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.stackoverflow.UdpListener.utilityQueue", qos: .utility)
        udpSock = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: utilityQueue)

        do {
            try udpSock!.bind(toPort: listenPort, interface: "lo0")
        } catch {
            print("Issue with binding to Port")
            return
        }

        do {
            try udpSock!.beginReceiving()
        } catch {
            print("Issue with receciving data")
            return
        }
    }

    func sendData() {
        udpSock!.send(data!, toHost: toAddress, port: connectPort, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
    }

    // Delegate CallBacks
    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data, withFilterContext filterContext: Any?) {
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        if let str = str {
            print(str)
        } else {
            print("Could not decode received data")
        }
    }

    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didSendDataWithTag tag: Int) {
        print("didSendDataWithTag")
    }

    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didNotSendDataWithTag tag: Int, dueToError error: Error?) {
        print("didNOTSendDataWithTag")
    }
}
```